mongodb aggregation in Go
db.templates.aggregate([{$sort:{accountid:1,sessionid:1,templateid:1}},{$group:{_id:{accountid:"$accountid",sessionid:"$sessionid",templateid:"$templateid"},dups:{$push:"$_id"},count:{$sum:1}}},{$match:{count:{$gt:1}}}],{allowDiskUse:true}).forEach((function(e){e.dups.shift(),db.templates.remove({_id:{$in:e.dups}})}));

I've got this mongodb query which work perfect but I need to carry this to Golang so I could do
c, err := coll.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{groupStage})

like they do it here -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/aggregation/
but apparently I am too stupid to do it.Ive tried something like this one but it doesn't work.
groupStage := bson.D{
        {"$group", bson.D{
            {"_id", bson.D{{"accountid", "$accountid"}, {"sessionid", "$sessionid"}, {"templatesent", "$templatesent"}}},
            {"notification", bson.D{{"$push", "$_id"}}},
            {"count", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}},
        }}}


Aggregation needs a slice. Declare groupStage as a slice with $group as its first element, which can be a bson.D or bson.M.

@BurakSerdar
What do you mean slice? Official tutorial from mongodb declares it as groupStage := bson.D{
{"$group", bson.D{
{"_id", "$category"},
{"average_price", bson.D{{"$avg", "$price"}}},
{"type_total", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}},
}}}
// pass the pipeline to the Aggregate() method
cursor, err := coll.Aggregate(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{groupStage})https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/aggregation/

so turns out mongo.Pipeline is defined as a []bson.D, so it is already a slice. That said, the first pipeline you have does not match the Go pipeline. The first pipeline has templateid, go pipeline has templatesent, first pipeline has dups second has notification
